# Is it possible to create a extension, that records user browser history?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm now just researching now if it's actually possible.

Operation one: Access browser history, (and only return data from a particular website.)

Operation two: Write data to a xml/txt file or to the browser.

And what programming languages are best to do this ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Chrome extensions, there is the **[chrome.history API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history.html)**, which provides access to the user's browsing history.

If you developing a Chrome extension the programming language will be JavaScript.
Fortunately, JavaScript is absolutely capable of writing data to the browser (either in plain text or XML format).

Finally, using features of the **[HTML5 FileSystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebGuide/API/File_System/Introduction)** you can create a file locally (e.g. in the form of a blob) and invoke the browser's download manager (e.g. redirecting an iframe to the blob) for saving it to the user's computer.